# What is Protected Layer?

Tags: rigging, bones, linked-data

I found some explanation, but there is not difference between Protected and Unprotected layers for bones.

Theoreticaly if I have my bones protected it will be linked to scene after Make Proxy. But it is also linked with unprotected layers. If I will do some changes in bone hierarchy it is propagated to my scene too. So where is difference?

It looks like some old function from previous Blender version.

Comment: http://urchn.org/post/protected-armature-layers

Comment: I also found this link, but it is not true all yet. So I asked here.

Comment: I just posted the link in case you haven't seen it, often older resources are still valuable when explaining ideas and concepts even when the implementation has changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this differences:

If you add some constraint (IK for example) to your source blend with protected layers, it will be also in your destination scene.

You have to key your pose, because it will be reseted after reloading.

Answer (score 3):

It is to do with the way blender links armatures into other files. In the final video of [Humane Rigging](https://cloud.blender.org/training/humane-rigging/) Nathan says that non-control bones should be on layers that have protected enabled and control bones should be on un-protected layers.

Even Nathan doesn't explain it much but it has something to do with the way armatures are linked between the original file and the proxy rig in another file. We are not meant to modify any rig bones in unprotected layers once the armature has a proxy rig in another file.

Comment: Does this mean that every blender file with a proxy rig of the original would have a different or same rig bones compared to the original linked file?